# correct way of creating Stateless service Angular RxJs Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, observer-pattern

I need to maintain a stateless service using RxJs and Observables. So I have done this:

*Note:* Here I need to generate a work order number in a Reactive way and I store it on LocalStorage to avoid loos that Id on browser refresh/ App Killed use cases.

My doubt here is am I doing the correct way of creating Stateless service? If not what is the best way for that?

**Note:** All are working perfectly fine. But I need to know whether am I correct on this architecture or not?

*work-orders-data.Service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WorkOrdersDataService {

    private workOrderNumber: number = 1;
    private workOrderNumberSubject$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.workOrderNumber);
    workOrderNumberChanged$: Observable<number> = this.workOrderNumberSubject$.asObservable();

    constructor(

        private storage: Storage,
    ) { }



    setDefaultWorkOrderNumber(workOrderNumber: number): void {
        this.workOrderNumber = workOrderNumber;
    }

    setWorkOrderNumber(): void {
        this.workOrderNumber += 1;
        this.workOrderNumberSubject$.next(this.workOrderNumber);

        this.storage.set(LocalStorageConstant.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER, this.workOrderNumber);
    }
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
 async initializeApp(): Promise<void> {

     this.workOrdersDataService.setDefaultWorkOrderNumber(Number(await this.storage.get(LocalStorageConstant.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER)));
}
```

*work-order.component.ts*

```
    createWorkOrder(): void {   

          this.workOrdersDataService.setWorkOrderNumber(); // to generate new work order no.

 this.workOrdersDataService.workOrderNumberChanged$.subscribe((res: number) => {

        const workOrderNumber: string = environment.companyEnvironment.workOrderPrefix + res; // work order no. creation

      });

      }
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it *work*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe All are working perfectly fine. But I need to know am I correct on this architecture.

Comment: If `this.storage.set(....)` is a synchronous operation, this looks a good way to make ylur code reactive. You may just want to `unsubscribe` somewhere the subscription you create in `createWorkOrder()`. Last point about TypeScript style: you proobably do not need to define the types of variables you initialize. `workOrderNumber = 1` is equivalent to `workOrderNumber: number = 1`. Once you initialize it with `1` TS knows that `workOrderNumber` is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture is good and legit.

If you want to stretch the reactive approach, then convert `initializeApp` to an `Observable`.

No need to use a Promise here.

After all, the power of Observables is their global API abstraction over multiple APIs. (Promise / Fetch / Regular data structures like arrays/ etc...)

What I would do is:

```
 initializeApp(): Observable<any> {
    return from(Number(this.storage.get(LocalStorageConstant.WORK_ORDER_NUMBER))).pipe(take(1)); // take(1) for auto completion.
 }
```

and then subscribe to it in `ngOnInit` in your **app.component.ts** where you can and should call this.workOrdersDataService.setDefaultWorkOrderNumber

Notice that there is no `void` signature here, but `any` instead since it will lack the subscribe function argument.

Also, it might not be directly regarding this question, but I would consider a `publishBehavior` together with a `refCount` (refCount for auto subscription count) in your data service for a more "modern" writing over direct declaration of Subjects. (Which also allows you to use its **.connect** method to decide when to activate the subject rather then allocating it ahead in your data service).